# Grails REST 404 when hitting anything other than index

Tags: rest, grails

When following http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#restfulControllers in order to create RESTful webservices, I am getting 404 error when I hit anything other than index.

in my `Bootstrap.groovy` I have

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    new Restaurant(title:"mourne seafood").save()
    new Restaurant(title:"RBG").save()
}
```

in my `Restaurant.groovy` domain class i have

```
 class Restaurant {

    String title

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

and in my `RestaurantController.groovy` REST controller I have

```
import grails.rest.*;

class RestaurantController extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']    
    RestaurantController() {
        super(Restaurant)
    }       
}
```

I thought when reading the above link that if I call
`GET <domain>/restaurant` 
It would call the `index` method, which is fine, this works, however when I call
`GET <domain>/restaurant/1`
I thought it should call the `show` method with 1 as the `id`?  However I am getting a 404.  It works correctly when I hit `GET <domain>/restaurant/show/2` am I wrong in thinking that when the docs say

`GET    /books/${id}    show` in the mapping table that I shouldnt have to explicitly put `show` in the URL?

Comment: What is `<domain>/restaurant`? The url in Grails is `application/controller/action/id`

Comment: `domain` being `application`. `Restaurant` is the controller

Answer (score 0):

I know It sucks but here it is:

You need to create a generic rest controller and annotate the domain class pointing to it.

First delete the RestaurantController.groovy

Then create a BaseRestController (inside the src/main/groovy folder)

*src/main/groovy/BaseRestController.groovy*

```
import grails.rest.*;

class BaseRestController<T> extends RestfulController<T> {

    BaseRestController(Class<T> domainClass) {
        this(domainClass, false)
    }
    BaseRestController(Class<T> domainClass, boolean readOnly) {
        super(domainClass, readOnly)
    }

    @Override
    def show() {
        println 'showing...'
        respond queryForResource(params.id)
    }
}
```

Ps. I just override the index action to show it works
Now you can annotate the domain class

*grails-app/domain/Restaurant.groovy*

```
import grails.rest.*
@Resource(uri='/restaurants', formats=['json', 'xml'], superClass=BaseRestController)
class Restaurant {

    String title

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

You need to **specify the formats in the domain class** and not in the controller. Otherwise it will be ignored and XML will be default.
I named the api endpoint as **restaurants** instead of the grails default restaurant
Now you can HTTP your RestFull app e.g. http://localhost:8080/restaurants/1